# Installed app not working

Tags: android

I've got a problem with my android app. When I run and install it by `Android Studio`, everything is ok, but when I try to install it manualy from `.apk file` after installation it immediately close.
It does even on hello world app.

I have unkown sources turn on.

Comment: How did you find the apk? Did you get it from android studio?

Comment: Here MyApp\app\build\outputs\apk\

Comment: Or good! Is it working when run it an emulator? I guess this is caused by an exception in your app!

Comment: Yes it works, I tried to create new projekt with simply hello world activity and the same thing

Comment: Try click build then build apk again and check if it persists!

Comment: It didn't help but I update android studio to newest version and now works. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem **Happy Coding!**.